# How to find percentage of a number without using floating numbers in Python?

Tags: python, math

For example:

```
var a = 100;
var b = .3;
var c = a - (a *.3)
```

Notice that B variable has a floating number of 0.3 (which is for 30% of 100). The problem is that when Python prints variable C, it shows the final result in floating form, example: "C is 30.0"

I'm trying to make it so that var C prints as just "30" and not "30.0"

Thanks.

Comment: `var` is not valid Python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `int(c)` before printing it.

Comment: What does it do and how exactly can you call it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do int(a-(a*.3))

I don't know what else the problem requires. Using int() converts the float to integer